# Python - If Statment Not Working Properly

Tags: python, if-statement

this may seem like a stupid question but for some reason, I can't get this working.

```
print("1")
if print=="1":
    print("DL")
else:
    print("DSU")
```

I just trying to get the code to print "DL"

Although it just prints

```
1
DSU
```

This is for a bigger project although I have made this simpler version so that it makes sense.

Comment: `print` is for printing to the console, not something you can assign value to.

Comment: `print` is a function. It can't be equal to `'1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be the following for it to work correctly:

```
var = "1"
if var == "1":
    print("DL")
else:
    print("DSU")
```

As said in the comments, print() is a function so to check if the "1" matches the condition, put it in a variable.